# Inserting NOW() into MySQL Column When Login Is Made

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I'm trying to insert the current `DATETIME` into MySQL when a user logs into their account.
No error is shown on the screen, login is made but NOW() does not insert.
I have checked to see the column declaration in MySQL and it correct -- DATETIME

My PHP is below

```
         if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'] )) {         
          $query = mysql_query("SELECT username, password, image_name
                  FROM forum_login
                  WHERE username = '$username'
                  AND password = '$password'") or die (mysql_error());

                  $user = mysql_num_rows($query); 
                      if($user == 1) { 
                  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
                  $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'] ;
                  $_SESSION['image_name'] = $row['image_name']  ;

                  $login_time = mysql_query("UPDATE forum_login
                                             SET last_login = 'NOW()'
            WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'") or die (mysql_error());
              header('Location: http://127.0.0.1/tapmichiana/'); 
              die;
                } 

             else 
             {        

                         echo "<div class='OpenError' >";
                         echo "Username & Password Combination Is Wrong"; 
                         echo "</div>";

                 }
```

I have not shown part of the script for data sanitization and cleaning

Comment: The other answers are all correct, but one thing I need to point out to you is you have a SQL injection vulnerability. Sanitization/Cleaning is not the solution to SQL injection. Use MYSQLi with prepared statements for actual parameter safety.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't quote `NOW()`.

```
 UPDATE forum_login
 SET last_login = NOW()
```

Comment: Also worth looking at auto-timestamps in MySQL:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html

Answer (score 1):

Remove the quotes around NOW(). It's a function result you want, not a string containing NOW().